# How can I resize any kind of image?

Tags: delphi, delphi-6, graphicex

The goal of my project is to resize any kind of image (jpeg/gif/png) in Delphi 6.

I have tried many ways but I could not get the ideal solution. Any clue of how to do that? It can be a simple command line tool, some code or a Delphi component.

I tried imagemagick: that's too heavy : 20 megas + dlls + registry.

I tried some snippet but mostly of them ONLY work for JPEG. I need gif/jpeg/png

I tried graphicEX but does not load my GIF

Comment: I would personally recommend [`ImageMagick`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

Comment: Please see ["Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)

Comment: If you could tell about those *many ways*, you would avoid possible recommendations that you've already tried and didn't like.

Comment: I still use this one by [Andrew Jameson](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1896). It's good quality and works without all kinds of libraries. It works by assigning any graphic to TBitmap (one of the powers of Delphi), resizing the bitmap, and then assigning it back to the graphic again.

Comment: ImageMagick is quite heavy (20 megas) and needs some installation and some depedencies (dll, registry). 

I tried that but it was too heavy

It needs to work for jpeg/png/gif and not only for JPEG.

Comment: @user300675 Don't let the title fool you. It will work on other image types as well, as long as you can assign them to and from a TBitmap. If you find an implementation of TGifImage and TPngImage which support that, that may work too, although you may get trouble with transparency. It depends on the implementation of those classes. You'll have to find them anyway, since Delphi 6 has no support for Gif and Png out of the box.

Comment: 1) read [the book](http://www.springer.com/computer/image+processing/book/978-1-84800-194-7), 2) write the code, 3) ?????, 4) PROFIT!

Comment: take a look at **WIC** (Windows imaging component)

Comment: For something lightweight, I'd recommend graphics32 which has resampling filters I believe

Answer (score 9):

Using [`Windows Imaging Component (WIC)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it may look like follows. This code supports encoders for BMP, GIF, PNG and JPEG formats, but it can be easily extended to the other formats (for the rest of the native encoder CLSIDs, look at the remarks section of the [`IWICBitmapEncoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690110%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface reference).

Here's a prototype of the `ResizeImage` procedure used in this code example:

```
procedure ResizeImage(const Source, Target: WideString; Width, Height: Cardinal;
  EncoderType: TEncoderType; InterpolationMode: TInterpolationMode = imFant);
```

And here's a short description of its parameters:

- Source - input image file name
- Target - output image file name
- Width - new width of the image
- Height - new height of the image
- EncoderType - type of the output encoder; it can be one of the following values:

  - etBMP - for BMP encoder
  - etGIF - for GIF image encoder
  - etPNG - for PNG image encoder
  - etJPEG - for JPEG image encoder
- InterpolationMode - is sampling or filtering mode used when scaling the image; it can be one of the following values:

  - imNearestNeighbour
  - imLinear
  - imCubic
  - imFant

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  StdCtrls, Dialogs, ComObj, ActiveX;

const
  WICBitmapCacheOnLoad = $2;
  WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand = 0;

  SID_IPropertyBag2 = '{22F55882-280B-11d0-A8A9-00A0C90C2004}';
  SID_IWICComponentInfo = '{23BC3F0A-698B-4357-886B-F24D50671334}';
  SID_IWICBitmapSource = '{00000120-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94}';
  SID_IWICBitmap = '{00000121-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94}';
  SID_IWICBitmapLock = '{00000123-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94}';
  SID_IWICBitmapCodecInfo = '{E87A44C4-B76E-4c47-8B09-298EB12A2714}';
  SID_IWICBitmapEncoder = '{00000103-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94}';
  SID_IWICBitmapDecoder = '{9EDDE9E7-8DEE-47ea-99DF-E6FAF2ED44BF}';
  SID_IWICBitmapEncoderInfo = '{94C9B4EE-A09F-4f92-8A1E-4A9BCE7E76FB}';
  SID_IWICBitmapDecoderInfo = '{D8CD007F-D08F-4191-9BFC-236EA7F0E4B5}';
  SID_IWICBitmapFrameEncode = '{00000105-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94}';
  SID_IWICBitmapFrameDecode = '{3B16811B-6A43-4ec9-A813-3D930C13B940}';
  SID_IWICBitmapScaler = '{00000302-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94}';
  SID_IWICBitmapClipper = '{E4FBCF03-223D-4e81-9333-D635556DD1B5}';
  SID_IWICBitmapFlipRotator = '{5009834F-2D6A-41ce-9E1B-17C5AFF7A782}';
  SID_IWICPalette = '{00000040-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94}';
  SID_IWICColorContext = '{3C613A02-34B2-44ea-9A7C-45AEA9C6FD6D}';
  SID_IWICColorTransform = '{B66F034F-D0E2-40ab-B436-6DE39E321A94}';
  SID_IWICMetadataQueryReader = '{30989668-E1C9-4597-B395-458EEDB808DF}';
  SID_IWICMetadataQueryWriter = '{A721791A-0DEF-4d06-BD91-2118BF1DB10B}';
  SID_IWICFastMetadataEncoder = '{B84E2C09-78C9-4AC4-8BD3-524AE1663A2F}';
  SID_IWICStream = '{135FF860-22B7-4ddf-B0F6-218F4F299A43}';
  SID_IWICFormatConverter = '{00000301-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94}';
  SID_IWICImagingFactory = '{ec5ec8a9-c395-4314-9c77-54d7a935ff70}';
  // here's not TGUID type specified since the following formats are
  // used in the constant array of TGUID
  GUID_ContainerFormatBmp = '{0AF1D87E-FCFE-4188-BDEB-A7906471CBE3}';
  GUID_ContainerFormatGif = '{1F8A5601-7D4D-4CBD-9C82-1BC8D4EEB9A5}';
  GUID_ContainerFormatPng = '{1B7CFAF4-713F-473C-BBCD-6137425FAEAF}';
  GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg = '{19E4A5AA-5662-4FC5-A0C0-1758028E1057}';
  CLSID_WICImagingFactory: TGUID = '{CACAF262-9370-4615-A13B-9F5539DA4C0A}';

type
  PWICColor = ^TWicColor;
  TWICColor = Cardinal;
  PWICRect = ^TWICRect;
  TWICRect = record
    X: Integer;
    Y: Integer;
    Width: Integer;
    Height: Integer;
  end;
  PIWICColorContext = ^IWICColorContext;
  PWICBitmapPattern = ^TWICBitmapPattern;
  TWICBitmapPattern = record
    Position: ULARGE_INTEGER;
    Length: ULONG;
    Pattern: PByte;
    Mask: PByte;
    EndOfStream: BOOL;
  end;
  PPropBag2 = ^TPropBag2;
  TPropBag2 = record
    dwType: DWORD;
    vt: TVarType;
    cfType: TClipFormat;
    dwHint: DWORD;
    pstrName: POleStr;
    clsid: TCLSID;
  end;
  TWICBitmapInterpolationMode = (
    WICBitmapInterpolationModeNearestNeighbor = $00000000,
    WICBitmapInterpolationModeLinear = $00000001,
    WICBitmapInterpolationModeCubic = $00000002,
    WICBitmapInterpolationModeFant = $00000003
  );
  TWICBitmapEncoderCacheOption = (
    WICBitmapEncoderCacheInMemory = $00000000,
    WICBitmapEncoderCacheTempFile = $00000001,
    WICBitmapEncoderNoCache = $00000002
  );
  TWICInProcPointer = ^Byte;
  TWICPixelFormatGUID = TGUID;
  TREFWICPixelFormatGUID = PGUID;
  TWICComponentType = type Integer;
  TWICDecodeOptions = type Integer;
  TWICColorContextType = type Integer;
  TWICBitmapDitherType = type Integer;
  TWICBitmapPaletteType = type Integer;
  TWICBitmapTransformOptions = type Integer;
  TWICBitmapCreateCacheOption = type Integer;
  TWICBitmapAlphaChannelOption = type Integer;
  IPropertyBag2 = interface;
  IWICPalette = interface;
  IWICColorContext = interface;
  IWICColorTransform = interface;
  IWICBitmap = interface;
  IWICBitmapLock = interface;
  IWICBitmapSource = interface;
  IWICBitmapCodecInfo = interface;
  IWICBitmapEncoder = interface;
  IWICBitmapDecoder = interface;
  IWICBitmapEncoderInfo = interface;
  IWICBitmapDecoderInfo = interface;
  IWICBitmapFrameEncode = interface;
  IWICBitmapFrameDecode = interface;
  IWICBitmapScaler = interface;
  IWICBitmapClipper = interface;
  IWICBitmapFlipRotator = interface;
  IWICMetadataQueryReader = interface;
  IWICMetadataQueryWriter = interface;
  IWICFastMetadataEncoder = interface;
  IWICStream = interface;
  IWICComponentInfo = interface;
  IWICFormatConverter = interface;
  IWICImagingFactory = interface;

  IPropertyBag2 = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IPropertyBag2]
    function Read(pPropBag: PPropBag2; pErrLog: IErrorLog; pvarValue: PVariant; phrError: PHResult): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function Write(cProperties: ULONG; pPropBag: PPropBag2; pvarValue: PVariant): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CountProperties(var pcProperties: ULONG): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetPropertyInfo(iProperty, cProperties: ULONG; pPropBag: PPropBag2; var pcProperties: ULONG): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function LoadObject(pstrName:POleStr; dwHint: DWORD; pUnkObject: IUnknown; pErrLog: IErrorLog): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICComponentInfo = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICComponentInfo]
    function GetComponentType(var pType: TWICComponentType): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetCLSID(var pclsid: TGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetSigningStatus(var pStatus: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetAuthor(cchAuthor: UINT; wzAuthor: PWCHAR; var pcchActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetVendorGUID(var pguidVendor: TGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetVersion(cchVersion: UINT; wzVersion: PWCHAR; var pcchActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetSpecVersion(cchSpecVersion: UINT; wzSpecVersion: PWCHAR; var pcchActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetFriendlyName(cchFriendlyName: UINT; wzFriendlyName: PWCHAR; var pcchActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapSource = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICBitmapSource]
    function GetSize(var puiWidth: UINT; var puiHeight: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetPixelFormat(var pPixelFormat: TWICPixelFormatGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetResolution(var pDpiX: Double; var pDpiY: Double): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CopyPalette(pIPalette: IWICPalette): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CopyPixels(prc: PWICRect; cbStride: UINT; cbBufferSize: UINT; pbBuffer: PByte): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmap = interface(IWICBitmapSource)
    [SID_IWICBitmap]
    function Lock(const prcLock: TWICRect; flags: DWORD; out ppILock: IWICBitmapLock): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetPalette(pIPalette: IWICPalette): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetResolution(dpiX: Double; dpiY: Double): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapLock = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICBitmapLock]
    function GetSize(var puiWidth: UINT; var puiHeight: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetStride(var pcbStride: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetDataPointer(var pcbBufferSize: UINT; var ppbData: TWICInProcPointer): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetPixelFormat(var pPixelFormat: TWICPixelFormatGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapCodecInfo = interface(IWICComponentInfo)
    [SID_IWICBitmapCodecInfo]
    function GetContainerFormat(var pguidContainerFormat: TGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetPixelFormats(cFormats: UINT; var guidPixelFormats: PGUID; var pcActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetColorManagementVersion(cchColorManagementVersion: UINT; wzColorManagementVersion: PWCHAR; var pcchActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetDeviceManufacturer(cchDeviceManufacturer: UINT; wzDeviceManufacturer: PWCHAR; var pcchActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetDeviceModels(cchDeviceModels: UINT; wzDeviceModels: PWCHAR; var pcchActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetMimeTypes(cchMimeTypes: UINT; wzMimeTypes: PWCHAR; var pcchActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetFileExtensions(cchFileExtensions: UINT; wzFileExtensions: PWCHAR; var pcchActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function DoesSupportAnimation(var pfSupportAnimation: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function DoesSupportChromakey(var pfSupportChromakey: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function DoesSupportLossless(var pfSupportLossless: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function DoesSupportMultiframe(var pfSupportMultiframe: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function MatchesMimeType(wzMimeType: LPCWSTR; var pfMatches: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapEncoder = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICBitmapEncoder]
    function Initialize(pIStream: IStream; cacheOption: TWICBitmapEncoderCacheOption): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetContainerFormat(var pguidContainerFormat: TGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetEncoderInfo(out ppIEncoderInfo: IWICBitmapEncoderInfo): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetColorContexts(cCount: UINT; ppIColorContext: PIWICColorContext): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetPalette(pIPalette: IWICPalette): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetThumbnail(pIThumbnail: IWICBitmapSource): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetPreview(pIPreview: IWICBitmapSource): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateNewFrame(out ppIFrameEncode: IWICBitmapFrameEncode; var ppIEncoderOptions: IPropertyBag2): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function Commit: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetMetadataQueryWriter(out ppIMetadataQueryWriter: IWICMetadataQueryWriter): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapDecoder = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICBitmapDecoder]
    function QueryCapability(pIStream: IStream; var pdwCapability: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function Initialize(pIStream: IStream; cacheOptions: TWICDecodeOptions): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetContainerFormat(var pguidContainerFormat: TGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetDecoderInfo(out ppIDecoderInfo: IWICBitmapDecoderInfo): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CopyPalette(pIPalette: IWICPalette): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetMetadataQueryReader(out ppIMetadataQueryReader: IWICMetadataQueryReader): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetPreview(out ppIBitmapSource: IWICBitmapSource): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetColorContexts(cCount: UINT; ppIColorContexts: PIWICColorContext; var pcActualCount : UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetThumbnail(out ppIThumbnail: IWICBitmapSource): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetFrameCount(var pCount: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetFrame(index: UINT; out ppIBitmapFrame: IWICBitmapFrameDecode): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapEncoderInfo = interface(IWICBitmapCodecInfo)
    [SID_IWICBitmapEncoderInfo]
    function CreateInstance(out ppIBitmapEncoder: IWICBitmapEncoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapDecoderInfo = interface(IWICBitmapCodecInfo)
    [SID_IWICBitmapDecoderInfo]
    function GetPatterns(cbSizePatterns: UINT; pPatterns: PWICBitmapPattern; var pcPatterns: UINT; var pcbPatternsActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function MatchesPattern(pIStream: IStream; var pfMatches: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateInstance(out ppIBitmapDecoder: IWICBitmapDecoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapFrameEncode = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICBitmapFrameEncode]
    function Initialize(pIEncoderOptions: IPropertyBag2): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetSize(uiWidth: UINT; uiHeight: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetResolution(dpiX: Double; dpiY: Double): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetPixelFormat(var pPixelFormat: TWICPixelFormatGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetColorContexts(cCount: UINT; ppIColorContext: PIWICColorContext): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetPalette(pIPalette: IWICPalette): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetThumbnail(pIThumbnail: IWICBitmapSource): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function WritePixels(lineCount: UINT; cbStride: UINT; cbBufferSize: UINT; pbPixels: PByte): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function WriteSource(pIBitmapSource: IWICBitmapSource; prc: PWICRect): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function Commit: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetMetadataQueryWriter(out ppIMetadataQueryWriter: IWICMetadataQueryWriter): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapFrameDecode = interface(IWICBitmapSource)
    [SID_IWICBitmapFrameDecode]
    function GetMetadataQueryReader(out ppIMetadataQueryReader: IWICMetadataQueryReader): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetColorContexts(cCount: UINT; ppIColorContexts: PIWICColorContext; var pcActualCount : UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetThumbnail(out ppIThumbnail: IWICBitmapSource): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapScaler = interface(IWICBitmapSource)
    [SID_IWICBitmapScaler]
    function Initialize(pISource: IWICBitmapSource; uiWidth: UINT; uiHeight: UINT; mode: TWICBitmapInterpolationMode): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapClipper = interface(IWICBitmapSource)
    [SID_IWICBitmapClipper]
    function Initialize(pISource: IWICBitmapSource; var prc: TWICRect): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapFlipRotator = interface(IWICBitmapSource)
    [SID_IWICBitmapFlipRotator]
    function Initialize(pISource: IWICBitmapSource; options: TWICBitmapTransformOptions): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICPalette = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICPalette]
    function InitializePredefined(ePaletteType: TWICBitmapPaletteType; fAddTransparentColor: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InitializeCustom(pColors: PWICColor; cCount: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InitializeFromBitmap(pISurface: IWICBitmapSource; cCount: UINT; fAddTransparentColor: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InitializeFromPalette(pIPalette: IWICPalette): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetType(var pePaletteType: TWICBitmapPaletteType): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetColorCount(var pcCount: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetColors(cCount: UINT; pColors: PWICColor; var pcActualColors: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function IsBlackWhite(var pfIsBlackWhite: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function IsGrayscale(var pfIsGrayscale: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function HasAlpha(var pfHasAlpha: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICColorContext = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICColorContext]
    function InitializeFromFilename(wzFilename: LPCWSTR): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InitializeFromMemory(const pbBuffer: PByte; cbBufferSize: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InitializeFromExifColorSpace(value: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetType(var pType: TWICColorContextType): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetProfileBytes(cbBuffer: UINT; pbBuffer: PByte; var pcbActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetExifColorSpace(var pValue: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICColorTransform = interface(IWICBitmapSource)
    [SID_IWICColorTransform]
    function Initialize(pIBitmapSource: IWICBitmapSource; pIContextSource: IWICColorContext; pIContextDest: IWICColorContext; pixelFmtDest: TREFWICPixelFormatGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICMetadataQueryReader = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICMetadataQueryReader]
    function GetContainerFormat(var pguidContainerFormat: TGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetLocation(cchMaxLength: UINT; wzNamespace: PWCHAR; var pcchActualLength: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetMetadataByName(wzName: LPCWSTR; var pvarValue: PROPVARIANT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetEnumerator(out ppIEnumString: IEnumString): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICMetadataQueryWriter = interface(IWICMetadataQueryReader)
    [SID_IWICMetadataQueryWriter]
    function SetMetadataByName(wzName: LPCWSTR; const pvarValue: TPropVariant): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function RemoveMetadataByName(wzName: LPCWSTR): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICFastMetadataEncoder = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICFastMetadataEncoder]
    function Commit: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetMetadataQueryWriter(out ppIMetadataQueryWriter: IWICMetadataQueryWriter): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICStream = interface(IStream)
    [SID_IWICStream]
    function InitializeFromIStream(pIStream: IStream): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InitializeFromFilename(wzFileName: LPCWSTR; dwDesiredAccess: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InitializeFromMemory(pbBuffer: TWICInProcPointer; cbBufferSize: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InitializeFromIStreamRegion(pIStream: IStream; ulOffset: ULARGE_INTEGER; ulMaxSize: ULARGE_INTEGER): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICFormatConverter = interface(IWICBitmapSource)
    [SID_IWICFormatConverter]
    function Initialize(pISource: IWICBitmapSource; const dstFormat: TWICPixelFormatGUID; dither: TWICBitmapDitherType; const pIPalette: IWICPalette; alphaThresholdPercent: Double; paletteTranslate: TWICBitmapPaletteType): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CanConvert(srcPixelFormat: TREFWICPixelFormatGUID; dstPixelFormat: TREFWICPixelFormatGUID; var pfCanConvert: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICImagingFactory = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICImagingFactory]
    function CreateDecoderFromFilename(wzFilename: LPCWSTR; const pguidVendor: TGUID; dwDesiredAccess: DWORD; metadataOptions: TWICDecodeOptions; out ppIDecoder: IWICBitmapDecoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateDecoderFromStream(pIStream: IStream; const pguidVendor: TGUID; metadataOptions: TWICDecodeOptions; out ppIDecoder: IWICBitmapDecoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateDecoderFromFileHandle(hFile: ULONG_PTR; const pguidVendor: TGUID; metadataOptions: TWICDecodeOptions; out ppIDecoder: IWICBitmapDecoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateComponentInfo(const clsidComponent: TGUID; out ppIInfo: IWICComponentInfo): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateDecoder(const guidContainerFormat: TGUID; const pguidVendor: TGUID; out ppIDecoder: IWICBitmapDecoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateEncoder(const guidContainerFormat: TGUID; const pguidVendor: TGUID; out ppIEncoder: IWICBitmapEncoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreatePalette(out ppIPalette: IWICPalette): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateFormatConverter(out ppIFormatConverter: IWICFormatConverter): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateBitmapScaler(out ppIBitmapScaler: IWICBitmapScaler): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateBitmapClipper(out ppIBitmapClipper: IWICBitmapClipper): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateBitmapFlipRotator(out ppIBitmapFlipRotator: IWICBitmapFlipRotator): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateStream(out ppIWICStream: IWICStream): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateColorContext(out ppIWICColorContext: IWICColorContext): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateColorTransformer(out ppIWICColorTransform: IWICColorTransform): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateBitmap(uiWidth: UINT; uiHeight: UINT; pixelFormat: TREFWICPixelFormatGUID; option: TWICBitmapCreateCacheOption; out ppIBitmap: IWICBitmap): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateBitmapFromSource(pIBitmapSource: IWICBitmapSource; option: TWICBitmapCreateCacheOption; out ppIBitmap: IWICBitmap): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateBitmapFromSourceRect(pIBitmapSource: IWICBitmapSource; x: UINT; y: UINT; width: UINT; height: UINT; out ppIBitmap: IWICBitmap): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateBitmapFromMemory(uiWidth: UINT; uiHeight: UINT; const pixelFormat: TWICPixelFormatGUID; cbStride: UINT; cbBufferSize: UINT; pbBuffer: PByte; out ppIBitmap: IWICBitmap): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateBitmapFromHBITMAP(hBitmap: HBITMAP; hPalette: HPALETTE; options: TWICBitmapAlphaChannelOption; out ppIBitmap: IWICBitmap): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateBitmapFromHICON(hIcon: HICON; out ppIBitmap: IWICBitmap): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateComponentEnumerator(componentTypes: DWORD; options: DWORD; out ppIEnumUnknown: IEnumUnknown): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateFastMetadataEncoderFromDecoder(pIDecoder: IWICBitmapDecoder; out ppIFastEncoder: IWICFastMetadataEncoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateFastMetadataEncoderFromFrameDecode(pIFrameDecoder: IWICBitmapFrameDecode; out ppIFastEncoder: IWICFastMetadataEncoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateQueryWriter(const guidMetadataFormat: TGUID; const pguidVendor: TGUID; out ppIQueryWriter: IWICMetadataQueryWriter): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateQueryWriterFromReader(pIQueryReader: IWICMetadataQueryReader; const pguidVendor: TGUID; out ppIQueryWriter: IWICMetadataQueryWriter): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

type
  TEncoderType = (
    etBMP,
    etGIF,
    etPNG,
    etJPEG
  );
  TInterpolationMode = (
    imNearestNeighbour,
    imLinear,
    imCubic,
    imFant
  );

procedure ResizeImage(const Source, Target: WideString; Width, Height: Cardinal;
  EncoderType: TEncoderType; InterpolationMode: TInterpolationMode = imFant);
var
  FileStream: IWICStream;
  PropertyBag: IPropertyBag2;
  BitmapScaler: IWICBitmapScaler;
  BitmapDecoder: IWICBitmapDecoder;
  BitmapEncoder: IWICBitmapEncoder;
  BitmapFrameEncode: IWICBitmapFrameEncode;
  BitmapFrameDecode: IWICBitmapFrameDecode;
  ImagingFactory: IWICImagingFactory;
const
  EncoderFormat: array[TEncoderType] of TGUID = (GUID_ContainerFormatBmp,
    GUID_ContainerFormatGif, GUID_ContainerFormatPng, GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg);
begin
  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, nil,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IUnknown, ImagingFactory));
  OleCheck(ImagingFactory.CreateDecoderFromFilename(PWideChar(Source),
    GUID_NULL, GENERIC_READ, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand, BitmapDecoder));
  OleCheck(BitmapDecoder.GetFrame(0, BitmapFrameDecode));
  OleCheck(ImagingFactory.CreateBitmapScaler(BitmapScaler));
  OleCheck(BitmapScaler.Initialize(BitmapFrameDecode, Width, Height,
    TWICBitmapInterpolationMode(InterpolationMode)));

  OleCheck(ImagingFactory.CreateStream(FileStream));
  OleCheck(FileStream.InitializeFromFilename(PWideChar(Target),
    GENERIC_WRITE));
  OleCheck(ImagingFactory.CreateEncoder(EncoderFormat[EncoderType], GUID_NULL,
    BitmapEncoder));
  OleCheck(BitmapEncoder.Initialize(FileStream, WICBitmapEncoderNoCache));
  PropertyBag := nil;
  OleCheck(BitmapEncoder.CreateNewFrame(BitmapFrameEncode, PropertyBag));
  OleCheck(BitmapFrameEncode.Initialize(PropertyBag));
  OleCheck(BitmapFrameEncode.WriteSource(BitmapScaler, nil));
  OleCheck(BitmapFrameEncode.Commit);
  OleCheck(BitmapEncoder.Commit);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ResizeImage('c:\InputImage.jpg', 'c:\OutputImage.png', 320, 240, etPNG,
    imCubic);
end;

end.
```

You can download an extended demo project showing the usage of the above code [`from here`](http://code.google.com/p/projects-stackoverflow-tlama/downloads/detail?name=13588462.ZIP&can=2&q=) if you want.

Answer (score 4):

using GDI+ e.g. with http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=7 should enable you writing a converter very fast for at least BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, TIFF, ICON, WMF, EMF. You'd just have to load the graphic an paint it to a desired HDC using scale and translate transforms.

Comment: Second Bummi's suggestion. GDI+'s resizing includes all of the tasty smoothing and interpolation options and produces just beautiful, quick results. Since you're on D6, look at http://www.mitov.com/products/igdi+#overview IGDIPlus, which is dead-simple to use and is backwards compatible to at least D5.

Comment: @bummi Correct the link provided please.